# sed: toupper a character on a location

Tags: sed, text-processing, uppercase, lowercase

This

```
sed "s/public \(.*\) get\(.*\)()/\1 \2/g"
```

will transfor this

```
public class ChallengeTO extends AbstractTransferObject {
        public AuthAlgorithm getAlgorithm();
        public long getCode();
        public int getIteration();
        public String getPublicKey();
        public String getSelt();
};
```

into this

```
public class ChallengeTO extends AbstractTransferObject {
        AuthAlgorithm Algorithm;
        long Code;
        int Iteration;
        String PublicKey;
        String Selt;
};
```

I want to change `Algorithm` to `algorithm`, `PublicKey` to `publicKey` and so on. How can I transform the first character of the second segment (`\2`) to lower case?

UPDATE

`sed "s/public \(.*\) get\([A-Z]\)\(.*\)()/\1 \2\3/g"` selects "my letter" as `\2`, but if I place a `\L` before it it transforms too much (including `\3`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's an awk solution

```
awk '
$1=="public" && $3~/^get/ {
    sub(/^get/,"",$3)
    $3=tolower( substr($3,1,1) ) substr($3,2)
    $0="\t"$2" "$3
}1' file
```

output

```
$ cat file
public class ChallengeTO extends AbstractTransferObject {
        public AuthAlgorithm getAlgorithm();
        public long getCode();
        public int getIteration();
        public String getPublicKey();
        public String getSelt();
};

$ ./shell.sh
public class ChallengeTO extends AbstractTransferObject {
        AuthAlgorithm algorithm();
        long code();
        int iteration();
        String publicKey();
        String selt();
};
```

if you still prefer sed, here's a modification to your version, adding `\l`

```
$ sed 's/public \(.*\) get\([A-Z]\)\(.*\)()/\1 \l\2\3/g' file
public class ChallengeTO extends AbstractTransferObject {
        AuthAlgorithm algorithm;
        long code;
        int iteration;
        String publicKey;
        String selt;
};
```

Comment: I believe that a sed one-liner should solve my problem. I wouldn't go to awk only if the sed way become too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

This is nearly identical to [upper- to lower-case using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689495/upper-to-lower-case-using-sed).

EDIT:  The question/answer there uses the `\L` GNU `sed` extension.  The conversion begun by `\L` can be turned off by `\E`, so if you tease out "your letter" into `\2`, you can put a `\L` before it and a `\E` immediately after it.

See the [GNU `sed` documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) for more information.

If you don't have GNU extensions, you can do this with two separate `sed` commands.  You can use the `y` command to change a character that matches one of a source character into a corresponding destination character.  This is similar to the Unix utility `tr`.

Comment: The `\L` transforms the whole rest. `PublicKey` into `publickey` not `publicKey`. Updating question with this bit of info. +1

Comment: The first part of the edit is awesome. Thank you. I am sad I cannot give more points :-). The second is not location dependent, so it is not good for me.