# BASH - Make the first Letter Uppercase

Tags: bash, string, capitalization

I try to capitalize the first letter in a CSV which is sorted like this:

> a23;asd23;sdg3

What i want is a output like this

> a23;Asd23;Sdg3

So the first String should be as is, but the second and third should have a capitalized first letter. I tried with AWK and SED but i didn't find the right solution. Can someone help?

Comment: Thank you all. Bart Sas' answer fits perfect my needs. :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just capitilise all letters that follow a semicolon:

```
sed -e 's/;./\U&\E/g'
```

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what i've searched. :-)

Comment: Some explanation is in order, since regexes in `sed` have their own special features. `\U` converts all characters to the right to uppercase, `&` is (probably) the same as `\0`, `\E` unnecessarily stops conversion. Here's a link another answer that explains it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2762997/521032

Answer (score 7):

Bash (version 4 and up) has a "first uppercase" operator, `${var^}`, but in this case I think it is better to use `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/(^|;)(.)/\1\U\2/g' <<< "a23;asd23;sdg3"
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `${var^}`, it did the trick for me!

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "a23;asd23;sdg3" | perl -ne 's/(?<=\W)(\w)/ uc($1) /gex;print $_'

a23;Asd23;Sdg3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ var="a23;asd23;sdg3"
$ echo $var | awk -F";" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) $i=toupper(substr($i,i,1))substr($i,1) }1' OFS=";"
a23;Sasd23;Gsdg3
```