# Replace string with substring in lowercase using sed / awk / tr / perl?

Tags: perl, sed, awk, tr

I have a plaintext file containing multiple instances of the pattern `$$DATABASE_*$$` and the asterisk could be any string of characters.  I'd like to replace the entire instance with whatever is in the asterisk portion, but lowercase.

Here is a test file:

```
$$DATABASE_GIBSON$$

test me $$DATABASE_GIBSON$$ test me

$$DATABASE_GIBSON$$ test $$DATABASE_GIBSON$$ test

$$DATABASE_GIBSON$$ $$DATABASE_GIBSON$$$$DATABASE_GIBSON$$
```

Here is the desired output:

```
gibson

test me gibson test me

gibson test gibson test

gibson gibsongibson
```

How do I do this with sed/awk/tr/perl?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4569825/318716

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/689495/318716

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the perl version I ended up using.

```
perl -p -i.bak -e 's/\$\$DATABASE_(.*?)\$\$/lc($1)/eg' inputFile
```

Comment: Nice solution indeed. Note however, that it won't work if `*` contains newlines.

Answer (score 1):

This one works with complicated examples.

```
perl -ple 's/\$\$DATABASE_(.*?)\$\$/lc($1)/eg' filename.txt
```

And for simpler examples :

```
echo '$$DATABASE_GIBSON$$' | sed 's@$$DATABASE_\(.*\)\$\$@\L\1@'
```

in [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), `\L` means lower case (`\E` to stop if needed)

Comment: Not quite.  I'm using this test file: http://pastebin.com/Q6RvvdcD

And the output looks like this: http://pastebin.com/CBe0Mehb

Comment: Added perl portable solution.

Comment: With the same input file as above, using the perl, I get this: http://pastebin.com/y2uFq1Xk

That one is seriously messing with formatting and deleting things.

Comment: @anubhava - it doesn't work on OSX because \L an \E are GNU sed isms.  This answer works in most Linux environments, but is not portable.

Comment: FYI I'm in a FreeBSD environment.

Comment: @BlueJ774 - as am I.  OSX and FreeBSD use the same sed.

Comment: See my new perl command in my POST : `perl -ple 's/\$\$DATABASE_(.*?)\$\$/lc($1)/eg' filename.txt`

Comment: `\L` means `lc()` in Perl as well you know.

Comment: @sputnick: What is the difference between your updated perl solution and the solution posted and accepted by the OP half an hour before your edit?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no easy, foolproof way with awk, but here's one approach:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
   gsub(/[$][$]/,"\n")

   head = ""
   tail = $0

   while ( match(tail, "\nDATABASE_[^\n]+\n") ) {
      head = head substr(tail,1,RSTART-1)
      trgt = substr(tail,RSTART,RLENGTH)
      tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH)

      gsub(/\n(DATABASE_)?/,"",trgt)

      head = head tolower(trgt)

   }

   $0 = head tail

   gsub("\n","$$")

   print
}

$ cat file
The quick brown $$DATABASE_FOX$$ jumped over the lazy $$DATABASE_DOG$$s back.
The grey $$DATABASE_SQUIRREL$$ ate $$DATABASE_NUT$$s under a $$DATABASE_TREE$$.
Put a dollar $$DATABASE_DOL$LAR$$ in the $$ string.

$ awk -f tst.awk file
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back.
The grey squirrel ate nuts under a tree.
Put a dollar dol$lar in the $$ string.
```

Note the trick of converting $$ to a newline char so we can negate that char in the match(RE), without that (i.e. if we used ".+" instead of "[^\n]+") then due to greedy RE matching if the same pattern appeared twice on one input line the matching string would extend from the start of the first pattern to the end of the second pattern.

Comment: Nice code. Would you mind commenting on [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18484993/2451238)? I think I solved the problem with very little (`g`)`awk`. It should even work with newlines within the `*` string. But maybe I got something wrong. In this case I would like to lern from this. :)

Comment: It doesn't produce the expected output from the sample input in the question.

Comment: For me it does. Did you use GNU `awk` `gawk`? IIRC, POSIX `awk` does not support regular expression (RE) record separators (RS). If you tested it using `gawk`, what is the output you got and which version did you use?

Comment: Yes I use gawk 4.1.1. The final line of output is `gibson gibson` with no terminating newline instead of `gibson gibsongibson` with a terminating newline.

Comment: Thx for your input. The terminating newline was missing since `ORS` was empty in the case of the last record. Thus the assignment evaluated to false, not triggering the print. I fixed that by wrapping the assignment into an unconditioned *action* and adding an unconditioned `print` using the `1` idiom. However, the `$$DATABASE_GIBSON$$$$DATABASE_GIBSON$$` part is tramsformed to `gibsongibson` as expected for me. Can you double-check that this is stil not the case for you with my latest version? I'm on `gawk 4.0.2` so maybe sth changed since then. I'll try a recent `gawk` later today. Thx.

Comment: My bad, I'd missed the last `$` off the input when I copy/pasted it. It's working now, looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk alone:

```
> echo '$$DATABASE_AWESOME$$' | awk '{sub(/.*_/,"");sub(/\$\$$/,"");print tolower($0);}'
awesome
```

Note that I'm in FreeBSD, so this is not GNU awk.

But this can be done using bash alone:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ foo='$$DATABASE_AWESOME$$'
[ghoti@pc ~]$ foo=${foo##*_}
[ghoti@pc ~]$ foo=${foo%\$\$}
[ghoti@pc ~]$ foo=${foo,,}
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo $foo
awesome
```

Of the above substitutions, all except the last one (`${foo,,}`) will work in standard Bourne shell.  If you don't have bash, you can instead do use `tr` for this step:

```
$ echo $foo
AWESOME
$ foo=$(echo "$foo" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
$ echo $foo
awesome
$
```

**UPDATE**:

Per comments, it seems that what the OP *really* wants is to strip the substring out of *any text in which it is included* -- that is, our solutions need to account for the possibility of leading or trailing spaces, before or after the string he provided in his question.

```
> echo 'foo $$DATABASE_KITTENS$$ bar' | sed -nE '/\$\$[^$]+\$\$/{;s/.*\$\$DATABASE_//;s/\$\$.*//;p;}' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
kittens
```

And if you happen to have `pcregrep` on your path (from the `devel/pcre` FreeBSD port), you can use that instead, with lookaheads:

```
> echo 'foo $$DATABASE_KITTENS$$ bar' | pcregrep -o '(?!\$\$DATABASE_)[A-Z]+(?=\$\$)' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
kittens
```

(For Linux users reading this: this is equivalent to using `grep -P`.)

And in pure bash:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ foo='foo $$DATABASE_KITTENS$$ bar'
$ foo=${foo##*(?)\$\$DATABASE_}
$ foo=${foo%%\$\$*(?)}
$ foo=${foo,,}
$ echo $foo
kittens
```

Note that NONE of these three updated solutions will handle situations where multiple tagged database names exist in the *same line of input*.  That's not stated as a requirement in the question either, but I'm just sayin'....

Comment: Close, but not quite with awk.  Input: http://pastebin.com/Q6RvvdcD
Output: http://pastebin.com/66HLeqgt

Comment: Those samples are not included in your question.  I answered the question posted.

Comment: @BlueJ774 - updated my answer with your new requirements.  You might want to be more explicit [in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13073727/edit) to avoid confusion.

Comment: Nice answer, but even your updated version does not do what (current version of) the question asks for: It will remove all input *not* to be transformed to lowercase instead of outputting it as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a pretty foolproof way with the supercool command cut :)

```
echo '$$DATABASE_AWESOME$$' | cut -d'$' -f3 | cut -d_ -f2 | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/$\$/\n/g;s/\nDATABASE_\([^\n]*\)\n/\L\1/g;s/\n/$$/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the shortest (GNU) `awk` solution I could come up with that does everything requested by the OP:

```sh
awk -vRS='[$][$]DATABASE_([^$]+[$])+[$]' '{ORS=tolower(substr(RT,12,length(RT)-13))}1'
```

Even if the string indicated with the asterix (`*`) contained one or more single Dollar signs (`$`) and/or linebreaks this soultion should still work.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub(/\$\$DATABASE_GIBSON\$\$/,"gibson")}1' file
gibson

test me gibson test me

gibson test gibson test

gibson gibsongibson
```

Answer (score -1):

`echo $$DATABASE_WOOLY$$ | awk '{print tolower($0)}'`

awk will take what ever input, in this case the first agurment, and use the `tolower` function and return the results.

For your bash script you can do something like this and use the variable `DBLOWER`

```
DBLOWER=$(echo $$DATABASE_WOOLY$$ | awk '{print tolower($0)}');
```

Comment: This is not replacing `$$DATABASE_*$$` by `*` as requested by the OP. Also it will convert *all* the input to lower case.