# How to replace lower case with sed

Tags: bash, sed

```
SET_VALUE(ab.ms.r.gms_dil_cfg.f().gms_dil_mode, dsad_sd );
```

How can I use `sed` to replace only from the `SET_VALUE` until the , with each letter after `_` to be upper case?

result:

```
SET_VALUE(ab.ms.r.gmsDilCfg.f().gmsDilMode, dsad_sd );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [upper- to lower-case using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689495/upper-to-lower-case-using-sed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your input string you may apply the following ***sed*** expression + ***bash*** variable substitution:

```
s="SET_VALUE(ab.ms.r.gms_dil_cfg.f().gms_dil_mode, dsad sd )"
res=$(sed '1s/_\([a-z]\)/\U\1/g;' <<< "${s%,*}"),${s#*,}
echo "$res"
```

The output:

```
SET_VALUE(ab.ms.r.gmsDilCfg.f().gmsDilMode, dsad_sd );
```

Comment: there is _ in the second term which i don't want to be affected.. dsad_sd

Comment: `\U` is a loan from Perl and is not generally supported by most `sed` implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Got distracted while writing this one up so Roman beat me to the punch, but this has a slight variation so figured I'd post it as another option ...

```
$ s="SET_VALUE(ab.ms.r.gms_dil_cfg.f().gms_dil_mode, dsad_sd );"
$ sed 's/,/,\n/g' <<< "$s" | sed -n '1{s/_\([a-z]\)/\U\1/g;N;s/\n//;p}'    
SET_VALUE(ab.ms.r.gmsDilCfg.f().gmsDilMode, dsad_sd );
```

- `s/,/,\n/g` : break input into separate lines at the comma (leave comma on first line, push rest of input to a second line)
- at this point we've broken our input into 2 lines; the second `sed` invocation will now be working with a 2-line input
- `sed -n` : refrain from printing input lines as they're processed; we'll explicitly `p`rint lines when required
- `1{...}` : for the first line, apply the commands inside the braces ...
- `s/_\([a-z]\)/\U\1/g` : for each pattern we find like '_[a-z]', save the `[a-z]` in buffer #1, and replace the pattern with the upper case of the contents of buffer #1
- at this point we've made the desired edits to line #1 (ie, everything before the comma in the original input), now ...
- `N` : read and append the next line into the pattern space
- `s/\n//` : replace the carriage return with a null character
- at this point we've pasted lines #1 and #2 together into a single line
- `p` : print the pattern space